# How do I edit (change color and border px) on bootstrap tabs?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: bootstrap tabs]

I have bootstrap tabs and the default color of the border around the tab is light gray. I want to color the borders all around the tabs from light grey to dark blue. I cant find the class or element to style it . How do I style all tab borders?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
       $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#invoice_selection">Invoice Selection</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#order_summary">Order Summary</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="invoice_selection" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table" id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr class="clickable-row">
<th>Select</th>
<th>Invoice Number</th>
<th>Due Date</th>
<th>Proce</th>
<th>Due in Days</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="clickable-row">
<td>
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" unchecked>
   </div>
</td>
<td>Anna</td>
<td>Pitt</td>
<td>35</td>
<td>New York</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="order_summary" class="tab-pane fade">
<h3>Menu 1</h3>
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the border color of the tabs like this:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
    border-left-color: darkblue;
    border-top-color: darkblue;
    border-right-color: darkblue;
}
```

Or a shorter way:

```
border: 1px solid darkblue;
border-bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav-tabs,
.table *,
.active a,
.table-responsive , 
 .clickable-row th {
   border-color:  #eaeaea!important;
 }
```